# Zip a Log4j-file from another date on startup

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I know that with log4j the user has the possibility to compress a file at rollover. But is there a possibility to stop my application, start it again on the next day and still compress the file, that has been created yesterday and therefore contains yesterdays date ? Due to the difference in the Filenames, because of the new Date, the old file is not compressed. Is there a solution besides creating a cronjob or similar to zip my logfile from the last day ?

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/server.log.${date:yyyyMMdd}" filePattern="${log-path}/server.log.%d{yyyyMMdd}.%i.zip">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%-16t] %-25c{1} %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="MonitoringLogger" level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```